# How to create following Request Structure in wso2 dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I want to achieve the following request Structure in DSS but i am not able to do this. The Structure is

```
:<body>
 <p:CreateReady xmlns:p="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">
  <!--1 or more occurrences-->
  <tns:Resistance xmlns:tns="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">
   <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
   <cct:ID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:ID>
   <!--0 or more occurrences-->
   <cct:Description xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:Description>
   <!--0 or more occurrences-->
   <tns:ResCategory>
    <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
    <cct:ID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:ID>
    <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
    <cct:CategorySourceID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:CategorySourceID>
    <!--0 or more occurrences-->
    <cct:Description xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:Description>
    <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
    <xs:ISO15926ReferenceURI xmlns:xs="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</xs:ISO15926ReferenceURI>
    <!--0 or more occurrences-->
    <tns:ResEntry>
     <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
     <cct:IDInChargeInSource xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:IDInChargeInSource>
     <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
     <cct:SourceID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:SourceID>
     <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
     <tns:ID>?</tns:ID>
     <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
     <cct:SourceOwnerID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:SourceOwnerID>
     <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
     <cct:Tag xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:Tag>
     <!--0 or more occurrences-->
     <cct:Description xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:Description>
     <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
     <xs:Inactive xmlns:xs="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</xs:Inactive>
     <!--0 or more occurrences-->
     <tns:ResProperty>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <cct:ID xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:ID>
      <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
      <cct:DataType xmlns:cct="http://www.axisSculper.omg/xmlnv/BCC/">?</cct:DataType>
     </tns:ResProperty>
    </tns:ResEntry>
   </tns:ResCategory>
  </tns:Resistance>
 </p:CreateReady>
</body>
```

I have tried with input mappings but am not able to achieve the above structure. Rest all are fine. Just need this structure as my request.Please help me on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you cannot have such a request format in DSS. You will have to stick with the request format data services creates for you when you define the input mappings. So to overcome this, you can use the WSO2 ESB to create a proxy service to take in this message format, and front the data service from it. Basically from the proxy service, using XPath, you can extract the parameters, create the message in the format that is required by the data service using the PayloadFactory mediator, and send it out.

In the upcoming DSS release though, it is planned to support custom message input formats in data services itself.

Cheers,
Anjana.